# How to write a ruby on rails condition for past date in utc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, conditional-statements, utc

For eg. If `today = 'Wed, 12 Feb 2020'` then,

The condition to write paste date, should return false as today's date is 12th feb. It should return `true` for all the date before today.

I need a condition in which today's date is not considered in past date in utc.

Comment: `Date.today.past?` returns `false`, what problem you are facing?

Comment: ```Wed, 12 Feb 2020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00``` 
I need a correct way to compare this date, whether it is in past or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wed, 12 Feb 2020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00` is `DateTime`, what you can do is convert it `to_date` and then call `past?` on it.

```
DateTime.now.to_date.past?
```

It will give you `false`

Comment: It's probably an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` rather than `DateTime`, unless you're dealing with a legacy Rails codebase.